# What's a good way to anchor the central bolts of a pair of gates?

Tags: driveway

So I've a pair of new handsome wrought-iron gates for the bottom of my (tarmac) drive. The gates each have a long thin "bolt" that is intended to go into a hole in the drive itself.

My initial feeling is that a couple of short lengths of metal tube set into concrete should hold them nicely. But, I'm concerned they'll soon fill with mud or earth or leaves and turn into a maintenance headache.

Any guidance? Should the tube be long (in which case I'll need a deep hole) or short (but this might fill up faster?) Would a bit of old copper tube I've got about the place do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it would interfere with the operation of the gates, but if you set that tube into the ground and left a slight lip sticking above the cement, that would probably do a lot to keep stuff out of the hole.

Comment: A jolly sound idea, I'll try that.